# Meteor and Mongo db - access value of a field in the current page

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

I'm new to Mongo and having trouble creating a javascript that can access a specific field in a collection for the _id that is already loaded on a page.

I've searched Mongo docs, Meteor docs and tutorials and StackOverflow and while some things seem hopeful they usually refer to getting the field of a known _id, where as in this case the _id is dynamically added to the page. So I want something like **"this.description"** where "description" is the desired field to capture.

Page is already loaded and successfully collecting Mongo field information using Spacebars. So for example for collection "products",

```
{{description}}
```

is showing as

```
I'm an excellent product!
```

for the unique product and description on the page.

Now in the page template js, how can I do the equivalent of

```
var thisDescription = {{description}};
console.log(thisDescription);
```

where it is going to return the exact same field value to console.log?

**I have tried this** in the template's helpers statement

```
thisDescription: function() {
  var context = FlowRouter.current();
  return this.description;
},
console.log(thisDescription);
```

...but it crashes the app.

**I have also tried** removing the console.log from the helper but leaving the function, and putting this in the template html

```
<script type = text/javascript>
  console.log(thisDescription);
</script>
```

...but it returns "thisDescription is undefined".

I'll jump for joy if I can figure out any way to get console.log to print the correct value every time the template is accessed.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to access the "description" field? In a template helper you can simply use the `this` keyword to access the data context of the template instance. So `this.description` should work just fine.

Comment: I concur: the data in the {{... }} is from the data context of the Template, so this.description should have your data if {{description}} has it (that is, if it's loaded already). With reactivity, you may need to check that it's not undefined and eventually it will be defined when the data shows up.

Comment: Mr.E and Tobold Would you be able to show a template helper example? I tried to invoke "console.log(this.description);" both in a script in the template html (result was "undefined"), in the template helper (result was app crash), and in the template onRendered (result was "undefined"). If it works I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Deborah - Here is what I would do to help you debug. I know this works in Chrome. Open up your Chrome console, type debugger as the first line of your thisDescription function and it will stop there. You can then see what the value of this is in the console.